# UNREAL ENGINE V4.21: Components not being initialized during constructor call for Character

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

We tried to initialize components inside our character's constructor. The code worked on v4.15 but not v4.21.

Here is our code (.h file and .cpp file respectively):

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "MainCharacter.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class VRET_API AMainCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this character's properties
    AMainCharacter();


protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public:
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

private:
    UPROPERTY()
    class UCameraComponent * camera;
    UPROPERTY()
    class USceneComponent * VRroot;
};
```

---

```
#include "MainCharacter.h"
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"
#include "MotionControllerComponent.h"
#include "Runtime/Engine/Classes/Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"
#include "Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ConstructorHelpers.h"

// Sets default values
AMainCharacter::AMainCharacter()
{

    // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
    VRroot = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("VRroot"));
    VRroot->SetupAttachment(GetRootComponent());
    camera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("Camera"));
    camera->SetupAttachment(VRroot);

}
```

The code compiles, but when we run the game our character's components aren't being initialized and we cannot find them in the editor during gameplay BUT the default character components (eg:capsule component) work and show properly.

Comment: Maybe it's a issue of blueprint on engine upgrade. You can try to add a new Blueprint inheriting `AMainCharacter` or create a new 4.21 project and copy your code into it

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. Try to unparent your blueprint class from `AMainCharacter` to just `ACharacter`, and then again parent it from AMainCharacter.
It worked for me!